# GridBagLayout in JPanel, components don't change x || y positions

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, gridbaglayout

I'm attempting to create my own GUI, trying to move the *playerWins* JLabel over to the far right. I've tried changing both x and y coordinates but the JLabel stays where it is. I'm wondering if it has to do with the JPanel being set as CENTRE.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DieIntGUI extends JFrame {

    public DieIntGUI(String title) {
        super(title);
        setSize(700, 700);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        initComponents();
        add(panel);
        add(errorMessages, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DieIntGUI frame = new DieIntGUI("Dice Game");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        errorMessages = new JLabel("T");
        playerWins = new JLabel("F");
        computerWins = new JLabel("S");

        drawComponents();
    }


    private void drawComponents() {

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setSize(700, 700);

        panel.setBackground(Color.white);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 17;

        panel.add(playerWins, gbc);

    }

    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel errorMessages;
    public JLabel playerWins, computerWins;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `GridBagLayout` would be.

```
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.weightx=1; //Fill all space
gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.EAST; //align component to the EAST
```

I have set x, y to 1. What's important to understand is that these are index's relative to other object that you add. (Has no sense if only 1 component, there are **no invisible grid locations**.)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much, I was wondering if there is a way to align JLabels? Is it the weight to add padding around it?

Comment: @W1492046 No it is how much relative space it will take if you add other components on same y, imagine that you have 3 componets on gridy=1 you can set how much of the relative space each component will have (the number is from 0-1), in this case we like it to take all the space and then we align it EAST

Answer (score 0):

This will move the label to far right.

```
public DieIntGUI(String title) {
    super(title);
    setSize(700, 700);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    initComponents();
    add(panel, BorderLayout.EAST); // Move to right
    add(errorMessages, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Output:

[image]

And yes, the `panel` was set to `CENTER` because in BorderLayout, if you do not specify a position, its set to `BorderLayout.CENTER` by default.

Comment: But he was using GridBagLayout ; )